# Finding last element in linked structure heap

Tags: c++, heap

I was wondering how you would go about finding the furthest element in a linked structure implementation of a heap and the root element. I want to be able to Enque and Deque elements.

Some clarification:
what I meant was lets say you have a linked structure making up a max heap (root element has the largest value). Your tree would have an element somewhere at the very bottom which you would insert after or remove depending on if you are enqueing or dequeing. How do you determine that element? and how do you determine the root node of the tree? (the top one)

Comment: The way is to cheat:  maintain pointers to the ending node (or parent of the ending node).  Also consider implementing pointers to the parent node.  This will give you better performance on appends at the cost of some extra memory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely positive this is what you are asking for, but this is one way of pointing to the last element of a singly-linked list:

```
T *p = NULL, *q = NULL;  // q follows p by one node
p = root;
while (p)
{
    q = p;
    p = p -> next;
}

// q now points to last node
```

Comment: +1 I think you beat me to it, if you use `while (p->next)` you don't need the extra variable `q`

Comment: Ah I already knew that one but what I meant was lets say you have a linked structure making up a max heap (root element has the largest value). Your tree would have an element somewhere at the very bottom which you would insert after or remove depending on if you are enqueing or dequeing. How do you determine that element? and how do you determine the root node of the tree? (the top one)

Comment: If you're using a linked list structure this answer works perfectly. You could add another pointer that is always pointing at the root if you want to always be able to access it. However, you mentioned a tree so now I'm confused.

Comment: When I say tree I mean a heap is a complete binary tree. Would this still work accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```
struct node {
  node *parent;
  node *children[2];
  int data; //or whatever else you want
};

struct heap {
  node *root;
  node *last;
};
```

This is a lot trickier to implement then just using an array though.  Here is a hypothetical add

```
void add(struct heap* h, int d)
{
  node* add = malloc(sizeof(node));
  add->data = d;
  node* current = h->root;
  while(current->children[1]) current = current->children[1];
  current->children[1] = add;
  add.parent = current;
  add.children[0] = NULL;
  add.children[1] = NULL; 
  h.last = add;
  percolate_up(h);
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: the thing is I want to search the binary tree (heap) and figure out what the last position is. I can set the pointer to root from the outset but I would have to do some searching to find the actual last value. Wondering how to go about finding the path to the furthest node in the tree.

Comment: the last pointer just points to the last element, and you update it every time you change the heap with an add or remove

Answer (score 0):

The normal method for adding something to a heap structure is to start at the root and "walk" the tree to find the place where the new element goes.  When you find where it goes, you put it there, and if that means replacing what's already in that spot, then you take the previous value and keep walking down to find where it goes.  Repeat until you hit a leaf, then add whatever value you're "carrying" as the appropriate child of that leaf.

Suppose your new value was 5 and the root node of the heap held a 10.  5 clearly goes below 10, so you look at the children of 10.  Suppose they're 8 and 7.  Both are larger than 5, so pick one (how you pick one depends on whether you're trying to keep the heap balanced).  Suppose you pick 7, and it has children 3 and 4.  5 goes below 7 but above 3 or 4, so you replace, say, the 4 with 5, then look at that node's children to see where to put the 4.  Suppose it has no children, you can just add a new leaf containing 4.

As for your question about how you find the root -- generally the root is the only pointer to the tree that you keep.  It's your starting point for all operations.  If you started somewhere else, I suppose you could navigate up to the root, but I'd question why.